# atom does not recognize angular 2 TestBed entries

Tags: angular, jasmine, atom-editor

Atom editing does not recognuze keywords of Angular 2 Jasmine TestBed (like describe, expect, it, beforeEach) are not recogized, even though I've installed all relevant atom snippets which I could find (using apm).

[MyComponent.spec.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HzNk.png)

Comment: Make sure you have the jasmine typings Look in your `node_modules` for `@types/jasmine` If it's not there, `npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine`

Comment: Of if you're not using `@types`, but `typings`, use `typings install --gloabl dt~jasmine`

Comment: @peeskillet don't we need to add even reference to the @types/jasmine in our spec.ts files?

Comment: @MrJSingh You shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install @types/jasmine and then you can add reference in your MyCoponent.spec.ts like this

```
///<reference path='../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts' />
```

Comment: Thank you, MrJSingh and  peeskillet - this one really worked:
I did not have @types/jasmine installed, and installing it  and modified the Jasmine files reference per the above worked like a  magic!